# Should I "start" tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I just noticed [a tag which doesn't have a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyclassname) but could arguably be said to be "specialized" - someone who's not a javascript user might not know immediately what it was - maybe they'd think it had something to do with object classes or something instead.

If I know enough about a tag like this to make a "stub" kind of wiki - i.e. a fairly bare excerpt and not much if any text - should I? Or should I leave it to someone who can create a decent initial outline?

If this were, say, wikipedia, I'd start a page with as much information as I had and let other users have at it, but I'm not sure how "wiki" the wikis here are.

How much is the smallest amount of a tag-wiki you should know how to write before you actually go ahead and write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should. I've created several tag wikis which were just a short description and links to some official resources. It's great for tag wikis to be fleshed-out resources, but their most important purpose is to specify the meaning of a tag. If a tag doesn't have a wiki excerpt description visible in the tag selector, people are more likely to misunderstand what it is and apply it incorrectly. (For example, there are occasional clean-ups for tags that have been used for two or more different meanings, where half of the questions need to be retagged.)

Comment: :) OK, thanks. I'll start doing that. I'll probably accept your answer at some point in the future, after giving others a chance to chime in.